# Array Index Out of Bounds Error While Populating From a Text File

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am having trouble with this error trying to populate the array from a text file. I think it might have something to do with my `if` loop, but I'm really not sure. It's giving me the out of bounds error on `myData[9]`. What I want to do is check to see if first letter is a `D` (meaning that the following stuff is an update), and then make an update object. My `update.txt` file only has 10 things in it to populate `myData` with, which is why I am confused as to why `myData[9]` is giving me an out of bounds error (specifically where I try to set it equal to `lastThirty`).

```
scan = new Scanner(file);
while (scan.hasNext())
{
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    String[] myData = str.split("#");
    if (myData[0].equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
    {
        recordType = myData[0];
        actionCode = myData[1];
        boxID = Integer.parseInt(myData[2]);
        movieID = Integer.parseInt(myData[3]);
        movieTitle = myData[4];
        movieGenre = myData[5];
        releaseYear = myData[6];
        inStock = myData[7];
        totalRentals = Integer.parseInt(myData[8]);
        lastThirty = Integer.parseInt(myData[9]);
        updates[count] = new UpdateRecord(recordType, actionCode, boxID, movieID, movieTitle, movieGenre, releaseYear, inStock, totalRentals, lastThirty);
        count++;
    }
```

The content of the file is as follows:

```
 H#Title Town Video Mart Updates#04\24\2016
 D#A#4#5#Harry Potter#Action#2001#True#50#5
 D#A#4#5#Shutter Island#Suspense#2001#True#50#5
 D#A#4#5#The Blind Side#Drama#2001#True#50#5
 D#A#4#5#Borat#Comedy#2001#True#50#5
 D#A#4#5#Bad GrandPa#Comedy#2001#True#50#5
 T#Title Town Video Mart Updates#04\24\2016#5
```

Comment: Your array seems to have no object in index 9. Show us your file.

Comment: Either one of your lines has less than 10 items or the file has more lines than your `updates` array can hold (you might want to make that a `List` instead of a fixed size array). It would be easier if you had indicated which line in your code the error occurred on.

Comment: It occurs on line 17 of the excerpt above. The updates object array has a size of 200, and there are only 5 updates in the file, so that shouldn't be a problem. I just double checked the txt file, and every update has 10 items, the updates constructor has 10 items, and I'm passing 10 things into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the txt is written, but probably the `String[] myData = str.split("#");` return only an array long 9, so accessing the 10nth element cause the error.

Consider for example that "boo#and#foo" should return a String[3]. Your txt to be functional should return a String[10].

Try to modify the txt to add another '#' and see if it works, or better see the content of the array in debug.

Comment: I edited the main post to include the text file data. The lines with a "d" seem to be formatted correctly, and my constructor for updates contains 10 items to pass in

Comment: Yes, the lines you posted seem correct. If you could see in debug what happens it should be easy to spot where things go wrong. Or even inserting some System.out.println of the array elements should provide some useful insights.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to use the debugger in netBeans, i did a println every time I populated myData with a variable, and it seems to be skipping the movieTitle, then throwing an out of bounds on the last index.

Comment: Another test you could do is to create a new txt with only one simple "D" line and try the program with it

Comment: Turns out the text editor in netbeans was not actually changing the file. I added in the movieTitle afterwards using the editor, but it apparently didn't change the actual file.